# What request is WordPress sending on theme update?

Tags: wp-api, automatic-updates

I am working on standalone theme update script and need to find out what 
request ( if any ) is wordpress sending when you click on update theme?

example info that WP "sees" for an update is this

```
array
(
    [new_version] => '1.0.5'
    [url] => 'http://someurl'
    [package] => 'directlinktoupdatefile.zip'
)
```

than you check the theme to be updated and you click  on Update theme button

**what does WordPress send than?**

I know it downloads the package  but does it send any request with it?

Reason why I need it is becuase I would like to restrict direct download and allow only WordPress to get the update file , 
so if anyone goes here  `directlinktoupdatefile.zip`  it wont  get anything

but if WP requests it,  than I can do

```
  if(isset($_GET['some_wp_equest'])){

   readfile(actual_file);
}
```

Comment: regardless of the specifics of your question, what you try to do will not work. It is basically a DRM and DRM on the web do not work without some "licensing" information being passed to the server. If you really need such a DRM I recommend to just buy the software licensing extension of EDD. The time that it will save you will be worth more than its cost. (there might be some other good solutions, I am just familiar with that one)

Answer (score 1):

WP send pretty much... everything with update request. You can examine `wp_update_themes()` for logic, but data would include something like this for every theme installed:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                   $request                                   │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
array (2) [
    'active' => string (6) "twentysixteen"
    'themes' => array (16) [
        'twentysixteen' => array (7) [
            'Name' => string (14) "Twenty Sixteen"
            'Title' => string (14) "Twenty Sixteen"
            'Version' => string (3) "1.3"
            'Author' => string (18) "the WordPress team"
            'Author URI' => string (22) "https://wordpress.org/"
            'Template' => string (13) "twentysixteen"
            'Stylesheet' => string (13) "twentysixteen"
        ]
    ]
]
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                $translations                                 │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
array (8) [
    'twentysixteen' => array (2) [
        'ru_RU' => array (4) [
            'POT-Creation-Date' => string (0) ""
            'PO-Revision-Date' => string (24) "2015-12-08 08:43:28+0000"
            'Project-Id-Version' => string (14) "Twenty Sixteen"
            'X-Generator' => string (21) "GlotPress/1.1.0-alpha"
        ]
        'uk' => array (4) [
            'POT-Creation-Date' => string (0) ""
            'PO-Revision-Date' => string (24) "2015-12-06 19:53:21+0000"
            'Project-Id-Version' => string (14) "Twenty Sixteen"
            'X-Generator' => string (21) "GlotPress/2.1.0-alpha"
        ]
    ]
]
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                   $locales                                   │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
array (2) [
    string (5) "ru_RU"
    string (2) "uk"
]
```

It's not very clear from your question what you intend to *do* with this though. Update process is historically a mess to deal with and is unfriendly to modifications. I would recommend to look up and study existing updater customizations over just trying to do this from scratch.